# Is the philosophy stack exchange obligated to feed the refugee academic with no access to libraries

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have met some academics who are refugees on temporary protection visas in Australia. They are not allowed to work or study and have a great need to keep relevant and up to date in thier fields of study, I assume preferably in their preferred language. A real gift of love would be access to materials and discussion through the stacks without fear or favour.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's being called for here -- SE is not setup to be a document repository; and the only wiki functionality really present here is for tags (which are naturally coupled pretty closely to questions and answers) and of course in spirit (the atmosphere and open format of the community)

Comment: Can you specify a little further what the action items here might be? What sort of particular events or activities could we participate in as individuals or a community that might help support these "academic refugees"?

Comment: I worry that "feed" the refugee academic might be a question of supplying them with articles they no longer have access to (so that they can keep up to date). If that is what is meant then in many cases this would be illegal.